# m2eclipse and RAD 7.x

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, m2eclipse, rad

I'm trying to install m2eclipse on top of RAD 7.5.5.4 but with no success.
Looks like all the threads about installing m2eclipse on eclipse 3.4 (which is what RAD7.5 is based on) suggest to install it from http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e-e34/
but eclipse says "no repositories found"

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: There is hope, though. Maven integration is included with RAD 8.5.

Answer (score 0):

a) Maven support got introduced in RAD 8.5.1. Select Maven when installing the product using Installation Manager.
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27024363#whatsnew_851_maven

b) If you want to start on RAD 7.5.x, you should go to the RAD Wiki
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/display/rad/Home
and review the document
"Java EE development using Rational Application Developer 7.5.5 and Maven"

c) If you want to use Maven on RAD 8.0.x or RAD 8.5 (NOT 8.5.1 or higher), you should review on the RAD Wiki and review the document
"Rational Application Developer and M2Eclipse: Maven in the development workbench"

Answer (score 0):

You can install Maven in RAD 8.5.1 only using the IBM Installation Manager.
You cannot install Maven using the update site.